# How to disable MYSQL Replication?

Tags: mysql, replication

I have 2 databases which are replicating each other with no issues. I required a test database server and to avoid installing OS etc, I started a new image of one of the servers (with different hostname, IPs etc).

Before switching on the interfaces I would like to be sure that the new test database will not send or receive and replication data from the other live servers. One easy solution is to remove IP routing towards the live servers, but I would like to disable replication too to be 100% sure. Can someone pls guide me how to disable replication so that the test server will not send any updates and not receive any updates?

Comment: You have 2 database _servers_?  Or VMs?  (Not two CREATE DATABASEs.)

Comment: "New image on server" -- Using Docker?  Or a separate instance with a different port number?

Comment: maybe i was not clear ... created a new VM instance

Comment: Configure (in my.cnf) binlog/replicate_do/ignore_*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL replication does not send anything. It's the replicas that must *pull* data.

This means if you haven't configured any replicas to connect to your test server, there's no way it can send any updates to other MySQL instances.

But to answer your question, you could:

- Disable the binary log on the test server. Then there would be no logs for any replica to pull even if they tried. On MySQL 8.0, you would set the server option [skip-log-bin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_log-bin) in your `my.cnf` file before you start the instance. On older versions, there is no skip prefix supported, so if you just don't enable `log-bin` in the `my.cnf` file (or comment it out if it's there).
- Identify the MySQL user that your replicas would use to connect, and use `REVOKE REPLICATION SLAVE` to remove the privilege from that user on your test instance. Or change the password, or just `DROP USER`.

That said, I also recommend configuring your network routing so test servers and live servers can't reach each other at all. Not only for the sake of MySQL replication, but any other contact.

Comment: thanks Bill! regarding your comment "This means if you haven't configured any replicas to connect to your test server, there's no way it can send any updates to other MySQL instances" ... were is this config entered? I am not seeing any config with the remote IPs that is why I got confused.

Comment: You're still stuck on the misunderstanding that the master holds any information about its replicas. The config is on the replicas, it is typically done with the [CHANGE MASTER TO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/change-master-to.html) statement. I can recommend that you read the chapter in the MySQL manual about replication. Or a book about MySQL replication like Ronald Bradford's [Effective MySQL Replication Techniques in Depth](https://www.amazon.com/Effective-MySQL-Replication-Techniques-Depth-ebook/dp/B009GI3NJW/)

Comment: went through the history of the other servers, and that was the command "change master to master host = x.x.x.x, master_user=userx etc ..... is there a way to remove this? 

managed disable the log-bin and deleted the user used for replication - thanks for that.

Comment: Change MASTER to MASTER_HOST='',MASTER_USER='',MASTER_PASSWORD=''; did the trick. 
show slave status is now empty

Comment: [RESET SLAVE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/reset-slave.html).

Comment: thanks ... added iptables on the live servers to make sure that the test server will not be reachable. now both show slave and show master are not returning any result too. nice weekend bill